# iOS: How to fix the following warning issues?

Tags: ios, xcode

Ever since updating to xcode 7. I received a lot of warnings that I am not familiar with and have no idea what they are.

```
warning: /Users/minidragon/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/HJUIXHI06SFW/CoreGraphics-1YQ59ILDR3NYI.pcm: No such file or directory
while processing /Users/tipsy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/rainbowtail-ceybamfcswlsqubjdieleicoaimx/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/libcocos2d.a(cpRatchetJoint.o):
warning: /Users/tipsy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache/HJUIXHI06SFW/CoreGraphics-1YQ59ILDR3NYI.pcm: No object file for requested architecture
while processing /Users/tipsy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/rainbowtail-ceybamfcswlsqubjdieleicoaimx/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/libcocos2d.a(cpRatchetJoint.o):
warning: Could not resolve external type c:@S@CGPoint
```

Does anyone know what they are and how to fix them?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

May be below solutions works for you.

**Solution 1**

Under the Project Target > Build Settings, change the “`Debug Information Format`” from “`DWARF with dSYM File`” to “`DWARF`”.

**Solution 2**

Deployment Postprocessing = Yes (`DEPLOYMENT_POSTPROCESSING=YES`)

Generate Debug Symbols = No (`GCC_GENERATE_DEBUGGING_SYMBOLS=NO`)

Symbols Hidden by Default = Yes (`GCC_SYMBOLS_PRIVATE_EXTERN=YES`)

See the relevant thread on Apple Developer Forums:
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/17921

Comment: hmm.. mind sharing what they are and what they mean? thanks in advance.

Comment: @tipsywacky Sorry I didn't get you.

Comment: I mean what is the difference between using DWARF and DWARF with dSYM File. Just a bit more details about the build settings.

Comment: Because it feels like the solution above is like hiding the warnings generated. So I am wondering if there is a fix to them or should I just ignore them.

Comment: ???   THIS Solution 2

Deployment Postprocessing = Yes (DEPLOYMENT_POSTPROCESSING=YES)

Generate Debug Symbols = No (GCC_GENERATE_DEBUGGING_SYMBOLS=NO)

Symbols Hidden by Default = Yes (GCC_SYMBOLS_PRIVATE_EXTERN=YES)         Doesn't Jive with https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/17921

Comment: I was using `GENERATE_MASTER_OBJECT_FILE = YES` (which was causing these warnings to begin showing) and the flag that helped me rid of these warnings was `DEPLOYMENT_POSTPROCESSING = YES`.

Answer (score 6):

If you use pods, add this to the Podfile after all the pod dependencies

```
post_install do |installer_representation|
    installer_representation.pods_project.build_configurations.each do |config|
        config.build_settings['CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES'] = 'NO'
    end
end
```

This will ensure that the build settings for the pod target anytime you install/update will have the right setting.

Then open the Pod target's build settings and for each third party pod set
`Enable Modules (C and Objective-C)` to `NO`.

Clean and build, the warnings should go away.

The solution suggested above by [Bhumica](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3432164/bhumica) only silences the warnings and will prevent you from getting useful information from crash reports.

PS: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/17921
suggests to do all 3 of the following, but I had to do only the `CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES`, `YMMV`

- `Precompile Prefix (GCC_PRECOMPILE_PREFIX_HEADER) = NO`
- `Debug Information Format (DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT) = DWARF with dSYM`
- `Enabled Modules (C and Objective-C) (CLANG_ENABLE_MODULES) = NO`

Comment: How would you write your podfile if you already have some code like "post_install do |installer|" ?

Comment: @MichiZH Then you just type `installer.pods_project.build[...etc]` in the second line.